# Drupal 8 ajax call backs and css id tag

Tags: ajax, callback, drupal-8

In Durpal 8 most places state that defining an ajax call back is done as follows:

```
$page['dateMonth'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Month:'),
        '#options' => $this->getMonthOptions (),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#ajax' => array (
            // Function to call when event on form element triggered.
            'callback' =>array($this,'testAjaxCallback'),
            // Javascript event to trigger Ajax. Currently for: 'onchange'.
            'event' => 'change',
        ),
        '#attributes' => array(
            'id' => array('month'),
        ),

    );
```

Where 'testAjaxCallback function exists in the same Form object.  When the above element renders should I see any code in the HTML code rendered to be able to know that the ajax portion of the code has been rendered or loaded correctly - in the sense that I can tell the '#attributes' portion of the definition renders because the HTML output in the form element shows (e.g. id="month"):

```
<select id="month" data-drupal-selector="edit-datemonth" name="dateMonth" class="form-select required" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

`<option value="" selected="selected">- Select -</option>
etc..`

The heart of the issue is that I am trying to implement a ajax call back request but am not sure where the problem is given the call back is not working e.g. is the problem at the point of rendering where the '#ajax' block of code is not being rendered (e.g. being ignored); or is the problem more associated with the testAjaxCallback function, in that the '#ajax' block is being picked up correctly.  My first port of call is to look for a figure print of the '#ajax' portion of the render definition having been picked up and acted on, if that makes sense.

Any help would be appreciated... for the sake of completeness as some people may become concerned the additional code dealing with processing the ajax code has not been given, then the testAjaxCallback function is:

```
public function testAjaxCallback (array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{

    // Instantiate an AjaxResponse Object to return.
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new ajaxTestAlert ());
    return $ajax_response;
}
```

And then ajaxTestAlert itself is an object which implements the CommandInterface requirement...

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\ajaxtestmodule_v1\ajax;

//**** core commands
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CommandInterface;


class ajaxTestAlert implements CommandInterface {

  // Constructs a ReadMessageCommand object.
  public function __construct() {

  }

  // Implements Drupal\Core\Ajax\CommandInterface:render().
  public function render() {
        return array(
            'command' => 'alertAjaxCommandRun',
        );
  }
}
```

And in the javascript at the client's side the alertAjaxCommandRun is defined as:

```
Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype.alertAjaxCommandRun=function (ajax, response, status) {
    alert ('it works!!!');
};
```

At this stage I've tried to keep it all simple hence the alert command in the javascript etc.

Thanks in advance for any help that can be given.

Answer (score 0):

To create a callback in the same Class you can use '::testAjaxCallback' like this.

```
$page['dateMonth'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Month:'),
        '#options' => $this->getMonthOptions(),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::testAjaxCallback',
            'event' => 'change',
        ],
        '#attributes' => [
            'id' => 'month',
        ],

    ];
```

In case that shouldn't work you can look in the console of your browser which will output any ajax errors that may have occured.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at this and response much appreciated... I tried the call back format suggested previous, but then retried it just in case - unfortunately it didn't resolve the problem ... I did also look at the console previously and again in the hopes as you say to see if there was any info i could obtain, but the console window doesn't return any errors... Thanks for the suggestions, hopefully it will help others too :)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work out that the culprit causing the issue was none other than the '#attributes' section of the render array =\ ... my question now is anyone got any ideas as to why?

The code that works for reference:

```
        $page['dateMonth'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Month:'),
        '#options' => $this->getMonthOptions (),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#ajax' => array (
            // Function to call when event on form element triggered.
            'callback' =>'::testAjaxCallback',
            // Javascript event to trigger Ajax. Currently for: 'onchange'.
            'event' => 'change',
        ),
        //'#attributes' => array(
        //      'id' => array('month'),
        //  ),

    );
```

So could it be that the introduction of an id attribute might have been over-riding what Drupal might have written e.g. overwriting an auto inserted name (by Drupal) somewhere in the code???  E.g. does this mean that we can't use the id tag in call back render arrays?

Hopefully this will help someone else and save them time in the long run.